# Image Recognition with Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, image-recognition

I'm currently following tensorflow tutorials.

If I would have a dataset, where each class contains a single image. Would TensorFlow be the best option?

Or should I copy & damage each image a little bit, so that I have multiple images in the same class? Similar to how they did number recognition..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use neural network implemented in tensorflow for image recognition. However, having enough training data is essential to achieve good performance. Of course it is not always easy to get more data, but one image per class sounds like far from being enough. So you should definitely try to achieve more data.

By the way, if you are talking about MNIST dataset (with regards to number recognition), it consists of digits written by high school students and employees of the United States Census Bureau ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database)).

One way to increase the amount of training data may be by modifying existing training data a little bit, but it is also worthwhile to try and to get more data in other ways. Otherwise, all your training examples per class end up too similar to each other.